# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'send_Keys' python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, attributeerror

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\nafi.DESKTOP-Q4U6HNF\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")


driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ytd-searchbox").send_Keys("venom")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("search-icon-legacy > yt-icon").click()

main()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'send_Keys'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send keys will work on input fields. You are trying to send keys on `ytd-searchbox` which will not work.

try send keys on following element

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='search']").send_Keys("venom")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use 'send_keys'(All alphabets in small case) and not 'send_Keys'.

**eg. element.send_keys("some text")**